# How can I change rename shortcut key to Enter (Return) in Thunar file manager?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shortcuts, rename, thunar

Mouse hover method works for all other keys expect Enter.
Editing `/home/username/.config/Thunar/accels.scm` has no effect and it reloads to previous values after logging in again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `"<>Return"` as the shortcut. For example, I was able to set the shortcut key for zoom-out like this:

```
(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarWindow/zoom-out" "<>Return")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked for me! I was setting it to `"<Return>"` but it seems `"<>Return"` is the correct one.

Comment: Sorry to open the issue again. Now I want to assign space bar to open file and folder properties window. There is a line for that in the above file with ` (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarStandardView/properties" "")` I tried <>Space but it did not work. Do you know what should I use for this case?

Comment: I don't think it's possible via accels.scm. It looks like spacebar is hard-coded to the "open" action. You could dig through the source code and manually change it, if you have the programming skills.